# Select array inner element

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a trouble with mongodb data below.
I want to get data `[projects][log][subject]`.
so, I tried like this

```
$project':{_id:0, projects.log.subject:1}
```

but it is not correct syntax..

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("569f3a3e9d2540764d8bde59"),
    "A": "book",
    "server": "us",
    "projects": [
        {
            "domainArray": [
                {
                    ~~~~
                }
            ],
            "log": [
                {
                    ~~~~~,
                    "subject": "I WANT THIS"
                }
            ],
            "before": "234234234"
        },
        {
            "domainArray": [
                {
                    ~~~~
                }
            ],
            "log": [
                {
                    ~~~~~,
                    "subject": "I WANT THIS"
                }
            ],
            "before": "234234234"
        },....
    ] //end of projects
}//end of document
```

How can I get data group by `[subject]`? I have no idea about this..

Edited-
I expected data like this

```
{
"subject":"first",
"subject":"second",
"subject":"third",
"subject":"~~~"
}
```

Is it possible? I just want to get array of subject.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the expected output?

Comment: Wrap `projects.log.subject` to be in quotes.

Comment: Can you please try to post a valid document with the expected result?

Comment: i posted again but I don't know form of result.. but i want array of projects.log.subject .. (set of subject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether it is your expected result or not. Can you please try this:

```
db.project.aggregate([
            {$project:{projects:1,_id:0}},
            {$unwind:"$projects"},
            {$unwind:"$projects.log"},
            {$project:{subject:"$projects.log.subject",_id:0}}
            ])
```

and Map-Reduce for above result of word count is as below:

```
//map function
var map = function() {

  for(var i in this.projects)
  {
      for(var j in this.projects[i].log)
      {

         var arrayWords = this.projects[i].log[j].subject.split(" ");
         for(var k = 0; k < arrayWords.length; k++)
         {
            emit(arrayWords[k],{occurance:1}); 
         }

      } 

  } 

};

//reduce function
function reduce(word, arrayOccurance) {

  var totalOccurance = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOccurance.length; i++) 
  {
    totalOccurance = totalOccurance + arrayOccurance[i].occurance;
  }

  return { occurance:totalOccurance };
}

//combine both function into operation and output result into wordOccurance collection

db.project.mapReduce(
                       map,
                       reduce,
                       {
                          query: {"projects.log.subject":"~~~~~"}, 
                          out: "wordOccurance" 
                       }
                     )

//query the result output

db.wordOccurance.find()
```

You can change the query under mapreduce to match your subject that want to word count. Please let me know if my mapreduce function doesn't meet your expected result.

You can also refer below two pages to create and troubleshoot map and reduce function:

[Troubleshoot the Map Function](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/troubleshoot-map-function/)

[Troubleshoot the Reduce Function](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/troubleshoot-reduce-function/)

Comment: Thanks it's perfect for me. thank you very much I wanted that data

Comment: And.. HaRLoFei, could you let me know how to use mapreduce using above result.
I want to count "words" in subject:"~~~~~". I just searched map reduce. It is suitable for counting words

Comment: Hi @Acool5 i have added mapreduce. Not sure it meet your expected result or not, pls post yours expected result if this doesn't meet.